# AWK multiline match

Tags: awk, multilinestring

I have read more topics about my problem but nothing has resolved that!

I have these text in my_text file:

Address dlkjfhadvkahvealkjvhfelkafver

Phone 4752935729527297

Discription fkdshkhglkhrtlghltkg

Misc 5897696h8ghgvjhgh578hg

Address klsfghtrgjgjktsrljgsjgm

Phone 5789058309809583

Discription dskjfvhfhgjvnwmrew

Misc h09v3n3vt7957jt795783hj

.....

.....

.....

And I want to filter this file data by 3 (or more) line value such as Address, Phone, Misc.

I test `awk '/Address/,/Phone/,/Misc/' my_text` but error!

Comment: try `awk '/Address|Phone|Misc/'`

Comment: Thanks alot...
My Problem Solved!

Comment: `grep -E "Address|Phone|Misc" my_text` will work too.

Comment: Nice GREP! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use or |  operator.

Matched line:

`awk '/Address|Phone|Misc/{ print $0 }' your_text`

Result:

```
Address dlkjfhadvkahvealkjvhfelkafver
Address dlkjfhadvkahvealkjvhfelkafver
Phone 4752935729527297
Misc 5897696h8ghgvjhgh578hg
Address klsfghtrgjgjktsrljgsjgm
Phone 5789058309809583
Misc h09v3n3vt7957jt795783hj
```

if you print ***$1*** you get Address, phone or what you matched. And ***$2*** will print your values only.